# QTableWidget: Only numbers permitted

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Is there any way to disallow any characters except numbers (0-9) in a QTableWidget? For QLineEdits I'm using a RegEx validator, but this is not available for QTableWidgets. I thought of inserting QLineEdits in as CellWidgets into the table, but then I had to rewrite an extreme large amount of functions in my code. So, is there any other (direct) way to do so?

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using an item delegate for your table widget to handle the possible user input. Below is a simplified solution.

The implementation of item delegate:

```
class Delegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
                      const QModelIndex & index) const
    {
        QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
        // Set validator
        QIntValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0, 9, lineEdit);
        lineEdit->setValidator(validator);
        return lineEdit;
    }
};
```

Implementation of the simple table widget with the custom item delegate:

```
QTableWidget tw;
tw.setItemDelegate(new Delegate);
// Add table cells...
tw.show();
```