# Only allow values in a QTableWidget column

Tags: python, qtablewidget

If I have a really simple [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) like the following:

```
data = ['first_row', 'second_row', 'third_row']

qTable = self.dockwidget.tableWidget
qTable.setRowCount(len(data))
qTable.setColumnCount(2)

for row in range(len(data)):
    for col in [0]:
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row]))
        qTable.setItem(row,col,item)
    for col in [1]:
        qTable.setItem(row,col,'0.1')
```

How could I make so that in the second column (where the default value is `0.1`), the user can only input values and not string?

Comment: by values you mean integers?

Comment: @ErikŠťastný - Ideally floats if possible :)

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708623/qtablewidget-only-numbers-permitted

Comment: @ErikŠťastný - Thanks for the link, I'll have to see how to translate c++ to python!

Comment: Or you can simple bind some code on Item change event but its not user friendly because it allow to write others character but after enter delete them.

Comment: Check my answer maybe this solution is enough for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this but there will be better solution i think.

```
   self.ui.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)

def item_changed(self, Qitem):
    try:
        test = float(Qitem.text())
    except ValueError:
        Msgbox = QMessageBox()
        Msgbox.setText("Error, value must be number!")
        Msgbox.exec()
        Qitem.setText(str(0.1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will test this and report back :)

Comment: @Joseph So Was the answer enough? Or you have any problem with implementation?

Comment: It's a good workaround so will accept it for now, thanks again :)